# How to remove vlookup function but keep the value in pragmatically from perl spreadsheet

Tags: excel, perl, spreadsheet

I am generating a xl file using perl spreadsheet, it contains 'vlookup' function for one column, the value which generated from the vlookup function is correct but I want to remove this formula and keep its value only,

How to do this?

I'm using

- Excel 2007 SP2
- Spreadsheet::WriteExcel: 2.40

Comment: Calculate the value in your perl script and insert that instead? Not sure what else you might mean here.

Comment: Actually my vlookup funtion like this 'VLOOKUP(B2,config!$B$4:$C$13,2,FALSE)'. 'config!$B$4:$C$13' values reading from a input xl file and write calculated data to new XL file and add 'config' sheet of the input file to newly created file, So its not easy to do it in perl scrip

Comment: If you don't want excel to evaluate the function and don't want to do it in perl either, then I'm not sure where you intend to evaluate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`=VLOOKUP`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) is an Excel function. That is, Excel knows how to calculate its result. Perl doesn't.

If you want to replace the `VLOOKUP` function invocation in the Excel worksheet with a value calculated by your Perl program, you are going to have to write a Perl function `VLOOKUP` whose behavior matches exactly with Excel's `VLOOKUP`, and invoke it whenever you find a cell containing `VLOOKUP`.

On the other hand, if, instead of using [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel), you use [Win32::OLE](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::OLE), you could replace the cell with its value.